# Footer not pushed down - tried everything already

Tags: height, footer

I have tried many possible solutions already, searched in here, but nothing worked, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I hope you can help? 
My footer won't be pushed down by the content, so when the viewport is not high enough, the footer just overlaps the content. I want the footer to always be at the bottom of the content (page). Not viewport.

Here are my styles:

```
        @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    * { margin:0; padding:0;}
    div { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */}

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #fff;
    }
    a img { border: none;}
    a { text-decoration: none;}
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        min-height:100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #header-outer {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 110px;
        background: url(../images/headerBG.png) top center no-repeat;
        background-color: rgba(39,53,99, 0.9);
    }
    #header-inner {
        width: 984px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 110px;
    }
    #content {
        width: 984px;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background:url(../images/contentBG.png) repeat;
        margin-top: 54px;
        padding: 0 0 80px 80px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #maincontent {
        width: 580px;
        height: 100%;
        float:left;
        margin: 80px 0 0 0;
    }
    #maincontent .imagecontainer {
        width: 164px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 5px 16px 5px 0;
        text-align: left;
        float:left;
    }
    #maincontent .imagecontainer img{
        padding: 5px;
        width: 154px;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(216,216,216);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(216,216,216); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(216,216,216);
    }
    .caption {
        margin: 0 15px 0 8px;
        font-size: 0.85em;
        color: #8398A0;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    a:focus{outline:0;}

    img.imgLeft {
        margin: 8px 18px 16px 0;
        float: left;
    }
    img.imgRight {
        margin: 8px 0 16px 16px;
        float: right;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'Rosario', sans serif;
        font-size: 2.125em;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #7FBE40;
        border-bottom: solid 2px #7FBE40;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #maincontent p {
        font-size: 0.875em;
        color: #556870; 
        line-height: 160%;
    }
    #mainside {
        width: 270px;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
    }
    #mainside p {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #8FA8CF;
        line-height: 180%;
        padding: 74px 60px 40px 18px;
    }
    .propsearchcontainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 270px;
        height:auto;
        top: 0px;   
        right: 0;   
    }
  #footer-outer {
        width: 100%;
        height:40px; 
        background-color: rgba(27,36,67, 0.9);
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #footer-inner{
        width: 984px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #facebook {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        float:left;
        clear:both;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #8FA8CF;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    /* Clearfix */
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
    .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
    .clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

    a.cboxElement {outline:0;}
```

And here my html:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header-outer">
        <div id="header-inner">
            <a href="" title=""><img src="images/mainLogo.png" alt=""></a>
            <div id="mainnav">
              <ul>
                    <li><a id="contact-button" title="Contact" href="">Contact</a></li>              
                    <li><a id="gallery-button" title="Gallery" href="">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a id="faq-button" title="FAQ" href="">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a id="news-button" title="News" href="">News</a></li>              
                    <li><a id="properties-button" title="Properties" href="">Properties</a></li>              
                    <li class="menu"><a class="link" id="about-button" title="About Us" href="">About Us</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                           <li><a href="" title="">Herrera Real Estate</a></li>
                           <li><a href="" title="">Our Services</a></li>
                           <li><a href="" title="">Herrera Interiors</a></li>
                        </ul>            
                    </li>

                    <li><a id="home-button" title="Home" href="">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End Mainnav -->
        </div><!-- End Header-inner -->

 </div><!-- End Header-outer -->

  <div id="content">

    <div id="maincontent">
        <h1>Herrera Real Estate</h1>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <a href="images/placeholder.jpg"><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="" /></a><p class="caption">Caption</p>
        </div>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a     
        more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using ‘Content here, content here’, making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page 
        editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for ‘lorem ipsum’ will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 

        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). t is a long established fact that a reader will be 
        distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to 
        using ‘Content here, content here’, making it look like readable English. </p>

    </div><!-- End maincontent -->

          <div id="mainside">
        <div id="propsearchcontainer">
            <a href="" title=""><img src="images/propSearchBtn.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div><!-- End propsearchcontainer -->
        <p>“Just a quick note to say thanks very much for the information I garnered at the course last week, I must say I came along with the usual reservations that you have about whether
        the whole thing might be very ‘Americanised’ and not relevant to our market but it was brilliant.”</p>
    </div><!-- End mainside -->


  </div><!-- End Content -->
    <div id="footer-outer">
        <div id="footer-inner">
            <div id="facebook"><a href="" id="fb-button" title="">Find us on Facebook</a></div>
            <div id="footernav">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="" title="">ABOUT GRENADA</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" title="">LINKS</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div><!-- End Footernav -->

        </div><!-- End Footer-inner -->   
    </div><!-- End Footer-outer -->

</div><!-- End Wrapper -->

</body>
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong here? I also noticed that my html and body are both not 100% height, when I use the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 100% height from #content div.

In this case (with no parent div height constraints) the 100% represents the height of the "viewport" and prevents the content from pushing elements, such as the footer, down beyond that.

```
#content {
    width: 984px;
    min-height: 100%;  /* This line is probably not needed either */
    height: 100%; /* Remove this line */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:url(../images/contentBG.png) repeat;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding: 0 0 80px 80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

*If* you find that you want the footer to appear at the bottom of the viewport when there's initially very little content, and then get pushed when there's more, then you need a JavaScript solution.